# Php FCM iOS Receive notification in background

Tags: php, ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am writing a general FCM function in PHP to send remote notifications to both Android and IOS devices.

In IOS I get notifications in the foreground but when App is in the background, I don't get any notification.

I tried several methods from the net and nothing helped me.

Kindly help me to set the server side properly

Try 1 :

```
$feildAryVar = array(
        'content_available' => true,
        'registration_ids' => $FcmUidVar,
        'data' => array("MsgKey"=>json_encode($msgToSendVar)),
        'notification' => array(
                "title"=>"Fcm TtlMsg",
                "body"=>"Fcm Dtl Msg",
                "content_available"=> true)
    );
```

Try 2 :

```
$feildAryVar = array(
        'registration_ids' => $FcmUidVar,
        'data' => array("MsgKey"=>json_encode($msgToSendVar)),
        'notification' => array(
                "title"=>"Fcm Title Msg",
                "body"=>"Fcm Detail Msg",
                "content_available"=> true)
    );
```

Ios App Deligate :

```
func application(appPsgVar: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

func application(AppPsgVar: UIApplication,
                 didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                                              fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
{
    handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    print("userNotificationCenter : Forground")

    completionHandler([.Alert,.Sound,.Badge])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void)
{
    //Code Todo After User presess notification
}

func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    let fcmNfnVar = remoteMessage.appData
    print("Received Notification : \(fcmNfnVar)")
}
```

Comment: There is notification come If you send notification from firebase and app in background ?

Comment: Have you implemented BOTH `AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` functions?

Comment: Yes I am implemented all